# Problem with Broadcast, BroadcastReceiver and Service in Android Studio (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, service, broadcast, receiver

I got a problem with my widget. I use broadcast to start a service in it, but actually my service is never used and I don't know why. Maybe You'll help me.
Here's my service. It is supposed to be something like audio player. Audio files are in .ogg format, in a raw folder that I created:

```
package com.example.projekt1_smb2

import android.app.Service
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.media.MediaPlayer.*
import android.os.Binder
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.Toast
import java.io.IOException

class MediaPlayerService : Service(), OnCompletionListener {
    private val iBinder: IBinder = LocalBinder()
    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
    private var songId = 1

    private fun setSong(songId: Int) {
        mediaPlayer.reset()
        val assetFileDescriptor = resources.openRawResourceFd(resources.getIdentifier("song$songId", "raw", packageName))
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(
                    assetFileDescriptor.fileDescriptor,
                    assetFileDescriptor.startOffset,
                    assetFileDescriptor.length
            )
            assetFileDescriptor.close()
            mediaPlayer.prepare()
            Log.d("setSong", "You set a song!")
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun initMediaPlayer() {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this)
        setSong(songId)
    }

    private fun play() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            mediaPlayer.start()
            Log.d("play", "You played a song! New SongId$songId")
        }
    }

    private fun pause() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            mediaPlayer.pause()
            Log.d("pause", "You paused a song!")
        }
    }

    private fun stop() {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
            mediaPlayer.stop()
            setSong(songId)
            Log.d("stop", "You stoped a song!")
        }
    }

    private fun back() {
        if (songId > 1) {
            songId = songId.minus(1)
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                mediaPlayer.stop()
            }
            setSong(songId)
            mediaPlayer.start()
            Log.d("back", "You changed your song to previous one! New SongId$songId")
        }
        else
            songId = songId.plus(1)
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                mediaPlayer.stop()
            }
            setSong(songId)
            mediaPlayer.start()
            Log.d("return1", "You returned to old song! New SongId$songId")
    }

    private fun skip() {
        if (songId < 2) {
            songId = songId.plus(1)
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                mediaPlayer.stop()
            }
            setSong(songId)
            mediaPlayer.start()
            Log.d("skip", "You skiped a song! New SongId$songId")
        }
        else
            songId = songId.minus(1)
            if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
                mediaPlayer.stop()
            }
            setSong(songId)
            mediaPlayer.start()
            Log.d("return", "You returned to old song! New SongId$songId")
    }

    private val audioPlayer: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.action == null) return
            when (intent.getStringExtra("button")) {
                applicationContext.getString(R.string.actionBtPlay) -> play()
                applicationContext.getString(R.string.actionBtPause) -> pause()
                applicationContext.getString(R.string.actionBtNext) -> skip()
                applicationContext.getString(R.string.actionBtPrevious) -> back()
                applicationContext.getString(R.string.actionBtStop) -> stop()
            }
            Log.d("broadCastReceiver", "broadCastReceiver")
        }
    }

    private fun registerAudioPlayer() {
        val filter = IntentFilter(getString(R.string.broadcast_test))
        registerReceiver(audioPlayer, filter)
        Log.d("broadCastReceivers", "broadCastReceiverxDDDD")
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder {
        return iBinder
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        registerAudioPlayer()
        Log.d("onCreate", "onCreate")
    }

    override fun onCompletion(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        mp?.stop()
        setSong(songId)
        Log.d("onCompletion", "onCompletion")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        stop()
        mediaPlayer.release()
        unregisterReceiver(audioPlayer)
        Log.d("onDestroy", "onDestroy")
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        initMediaPlayer()
        Log.d("onStartCommand", "onStartCommand")
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
    }

    inner class LocalBinder : Binder() {
        val service
            get() = this@MediaPlayerService
    }
}
```

Next is my widget code. It shows buttons that are used in a service to play, pause etc. music:

```
package com.example.projekt1_smb2

import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider
import android.content.ComponentName
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.net.Uri
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import android.widget.Toast

/**
 * Implementation of App Widget functionality.
 */
class NewAppWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {

    override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.new_app_widget)
        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_text, context.getString(R.string.appwidget_text))
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, 1, views)
        }
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent)
        if (intent?.action.equals(context?.getString(R.string.actionBtPrevious)) ||
                intent?.action.equals(context?.getString(R.string.actionBtPlay)) ||
                intent?.action.equals(context?.getString(R.string.actionBtPause)) ||
                intent?.action.equals(context?.getString(R.string.actionBtStop)) ||
                intent?.action.equals(context?.getString(R.string.actionBtNext))) {
            val broadcastIntent = Intent(context?.getString(R.string.broadcast_test))
            broadcastIntent.putExtra("button", intent?.action)
            context?.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent)
        }
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetId: Int, imgId: Int, views: RemoteViews) {
    var requestCode = 0

    val intentMusicPrev = Intent(context?.getString(R.string.actionBtPrevious))
    intentMusicPrev.component = ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget::class.java)
    val pendingIntentMusicPrev = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            requestCode++,
            intentMusicPrev,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonPrevious, pendingIntentMusicPrev)

    val intentMusicPlay = Intent(context.getString(R.string.actionBtPlay))
    intentMusicPlay.component = ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget::class.java)
    val pendingIntentMusicPlay = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            requestCode++,
            intentMusicPlay,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonPlay, pendingIntentMusicPlay)

    val intentMusicPause = Intent(context.getString(R.string.actionBtPause))
    intentMusicPause.component = ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget::class.java)
    val pendingIntentMusicPause = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            requestCode++,
            intentMusicPause,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonPause, pendingIntentMusicPause)

    val intentMusicStop = Intent(context.getString(R.string.actionBtStop))
    intentMusicStop.component = ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget::class.java)
    val pendingIntentMusicStop = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            requestCode++,
            intentMusicStop,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonStop, pendingIntentMusicStop)

    val intentMusicNext = Intent(context.getString(R.string.actionBtNext))
    intentMusicNext.component = ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget::class.java)
    val pendingIntentMusicNext = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            requestCode++,
            intentMusicNext,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    )
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonNext, pendingIntentMusicNext)


    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views)
```

And in the end declaration of service in Manifest. It's in the application section:

```
<service android:name=".MediaPlayerService" />
```

Comment: Which broadcast are you listening and can you share the broadcast receiver class?

Comment: Broadcast receiver is in the first paragraph and it's called "audioPlayer". It's inside of the Service. My broadcast is: "com.example.projekt1_smb2.MY_BROADCAST" and that's what's hidden under "getString(R.string.broadcast_test)". I send intent with "button" tag to mark which one of buttons was clicked and receiver recognizes it and starts needed function like play() etc.